# How to use HTML tags in element Popover component for Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

I am using Element Popover component (https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/popover) with Vue.js. The popover is working and I am able to display text content.

```
<el-popover
    placement="bottom"
    title="Title"
    width="200"
    trigger="click"
    content="this is content, this is content, this is content"
    >
    <el-button type="primary" slot="reference" circle style="background-color:white;border-color:white" >
    <img src="img/if_Help_1493288.png" alt="Help" height="42" width="42">
    </el-button>
 </el-popover>
```

Is it possible to show regular html elements, e.g. `<br>, <strong> or <img>` in the popover content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in [attributes](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/popover#attributes) description of popover component - content be passed through `content` prop as string or as a default [slot](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Slot-Content).

So any content will be passed as a `default` slot, if no slot name is specified. Here is an example for your case:

```
<el-popover
  placement="bottom"
  title="Title"
  width="200"
  trigger="click"
>
  <el-button type="primary" slot="reference" circle style="background-color:white;border-color:white" >
    <img src="img/if_Help_1493288.png" alt="Help" height="42" width="42">
  </el-button>
  <div>
    this is content, <br> <strong>this is content</strong>, <br> this is content
  </div>
</el-popover>
```

Note that `content` prop will be replaced with content of default slot if it is passed. Can't use them both at the same time.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks a lot for your help.